# jquery plugin doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

the jquery function ".textAnim" does nothing
textTyping_animation(); Works fine, but .textAnim doesn't work.
Here is the plugin code:

```
function textTyping_animation(text,location,speed){
var progress = 0;
var a = setInterval(function(){
    progress++;
    document.getElementById(location).innerHTML = text.substring(0,progress);
    if(progress == text.length){
        clearInterval(a);
    }
},speed);
};
(function($){
$.fn.textAnim = function(text,speed){
    var progress = 0;
    var a = setInterval(function(){
        progress++;
        $(this).html(text.substring(0,progress));
        if(progress == text.length){
            clearInterval(a);
        }
    },speed);
};
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the execution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
starttext = function()
{
    document.getElementById("textbox").style.display = "block";
    //textTyping_animation("Dit is een dummy text!","textbox_inner",70);
        $("#textbox_inner").textAnim("Dit is een dummy text!",70);
}
});
```

Html load code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jqueryplugins.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/libraries/gamelibrary.js"></script>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: "Here is the execution" is incorrect; you're declaring a function, you're never actually calling it.

Comment: @Qpirate, no error, div contains nothing

Comment: as @AnthonyGrist says, you are declaring a function and not actually calling it.

Comment: @anthony, I call it in an other file. "textTyping_animation(); Works fine"

Comment: If you're calling it in another file, **show us that code**. You can't expect us to help you if you haven't provided us with everything that's relevant.

Comment: start.js contains "starttext();"

Comment: Which of the JavaScript files in your `<script>` tags at the end of the question do those code snippets correspond to? What does the HTML for the page look like?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist let me put it this way:
I want to create a jquery plugin and execute it. Here is the jsfiddle url: http://jsfiddle.net/sQBbD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` inside the callback function passed to `setInterval()` is the window, not the element you want it to be. Modify your code to save a reference to `this` inside the `textAnim()` function (which does refer to the correct element), then use that inside the callback passed to `setInterval()`:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.textAnim = function(text,speed){
        var progress = 0,
            element = this; // this will be the element in the jQuery object
        var a = setInterval(function(){
            progress++;
            $(element).html(text.substring(0,progress));
            if(progress == text.length){
                clearInterval(a);
            }
        },speed);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Here's an [updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonygrist/sQBbD/1/).

Comment: Thank you verry verry much! (I did found the answer on another site were I posted my problem, but thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$(document).ready(function(){
starttext = function()
{
    document.getElementById("textbox").style.display = "block";
    //textTyping_animation("Dit is een dummy text!","textbox_inner",70);
        $("#textbox_inner").textAnim("Dit is een dummy text!",70);
}
});
```

to be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
starttext = function()
{
    document.getElementById("textbox").style.display = "block";
    //textTyping_animation("Dit is een dummy text!","textbox_inner",70);
        $("#textbox_inner").textAnim("Dit is een dummy text!",70);
}
starttext();
});
```

and it should work;

Comment: I did, in another file. But it only shows the div with id "textbox_inner".
When I am using "textTyping_animation()" it does work

Comment: Declaring a named function, then immediately calling it, strikes me as unnecessary if it's never being used again; you may as well just make that logic the body of the anonymous function passed to `$(document).ready()`.